# Using Timescale DB's Gapfill with JOOQ throws argument: start cannot be NULL

Tags: java, jooq, timescaledb

I have a Timescale DB running and am using JOOQ to access the data.

I am using `gapfill()` for

```java
dslContext
        .select(Routines.timeBucketGapfill5(
                Routines.createInterval(DURATION), table.TIME, null, null).as(FieldName.TIME_BUCKET),
                ifnull(count(table.STATUS), 0).as(FieldName.STATUS))
        .from(table)
        .where(table.ID.in(ids)
                .and(table.TIME.ge(Timestamp.from(Instant.now().minus(Duration.ofSeconds(DURATION)))))
                .and(table.TIME.le(Timestamp.from(Instant.now())))
                .and(table.STATUS.eq(status)))
        .groupBy(field(FieldName.TIME_BUCKET))
        .fetch()
```

Sometimes I get a

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid time_bucket_gapfill argument: start cannot be NULL
  Hinweis: You can either pass start and finish as arguments or in the WHERE clause
```

How can `start` be NULL if I always have a where clause with a greaterEquals and lessEquals?

I was able to log the SQL statement. If I run that query directly on the DB it works fine.

```sql
select "public"."time_bucket_gapfill"("bucket_width" := cast("public"."create_interval"("seconds" := 43200) as "pg_catalog"."interval"), "ts" := cast("public"."device_health"."time" as timestamp), "start" := cast(null as timestamp), "finish" := cast(null as timestamp)) as "time_bucket", coalesce(count("public"."device_health"."health"), 0) as "health" from "public"."device_health" where ("public"."device_health"."device" in ('700004', '700009', '700008', '700005', '700007', '700000', '700003', '700001', '700002', '700006') and "public"."device_health"."time" >= timestamp '2020-03-11 13:59:20.0564238' and "public"."device_health"."time" <= timestamp '2020-03-25 13:59:20.0564238' and "public"."device_health"."health" = 'OK') group by time_bucket
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the issue I now pass `start` and `finish` as JOOQ `DSL.val()` in form of a `Field<Timestamp>` and deleted the start/finish part from where clause.

I have no clue what exactly cause the error but this fixes it.

Here is the working code:

```java
var now = Instant.now();
Timestamp startTimestamp = Timestamp.from(now.minus(Duration.ofSeconds(DURATION)));
Timestamp finishTimestamp = Timestamp.from(now);

dslContext
        .select(Routines.timeBucketGapfill5(
                        Routines.createInterval(DURATION),
                        table.TIME,
                        DSL.val(startTimestamp),
                        DSL.val(finishTimestamp))
                                .as(FieldName.TIME_BUCKET),
                        table.HEALTH,
                        ifnull(count(table.STATUS), 0).as(FieldName.STATUS))
                .from(table)
                .where(table.ID.in(ids))
                .groupBy(field(FieldName.TIME_BUCKET))
                .fetch();
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you seeing the same error if you pass in those same args as the `start` and `finish` optional args in the gapfill call?  Are you able to capture the actual SQL that JOOQ is synthesizing?

(Aside, for more back-and-forth help, you might find slack.timescale.com helpful.)

Comment: I have a Problem filling the start and finish args becuase JOOQ generated the Routine 
timeBucketGapfill5(Field<Object> bucketWidth, Field<Timestamp> ts, Field<Timestamp> start, Field<Timestamp> finish)
which only allows a Field<Timestamp> which i cannot supply, because start should only only be a Timestamp

Comment: @SörenLinnemann: You can omit optional arguments in jOOQ by creating a `new TimeBucketGapfill5()` instance, and not setting those values to the instance. The auxiliary function `Routines.timeBucketGapfill5()` will always set *all* arguments.